# C++ Macro to get only even variadic arguments passed

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Would it be possible to make a `ONLY_EVEN()` macro to perform the following translations:

```
ONLY_EVEN0()
ONLY_EVEN2(a,b) b
ONLY_EVEN4(a,b,c,d) b,d
```

With any number of arguments, using variadic macro parameters?

Comment: You know there's some [bomb diggity documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) about it, right?

Comment: Its possible in C99, but as far I am aware its not possible in C++ (I may be wrong). But what problem you are trying to solve? May be it can be done with templates, not macros?

Comment: @sklott Variadic arguments in macros have been in the standard since C++11

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes. Again I can be wrong, but as far as I know in C++ `__VA_ARGS__` can only be passed to other variadic macro or function as ellipsis argument and you can't do anything with it, as OP asks.

Comment: With some limitations, it's possible. See here a closely related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308339

Comment: Don't use macros, just don't. Use proper functions ( possibly `inline`, possibly `constexpr`, possibly templated or whatever, but just use functions for crying out loud ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not for an *unbounded* number of arguments.

However it is possible for any variable number of arguments up to an arbitrarily chosen bound. For example, below is a self-contained macro solution for any number of arguments in [0..6], which can be extended in the obvious way to support up to any limit you wish.

```cpp
#define ONLY_EVEN0(a) 
#define ONLY_EVEN1(a) 
#define ONLY_EVEN2(a,b) b
#define ONLY_EVEN3(a,b,c) b
#define ONLY_EVEN4(a,b,c,d) b,d
#define ONLY_EVEN5(a,b,c,d,e) b,d
#define ONLY_EVEN6(a,b,c,d,e,f) b,d,f
#define ONLY_EVEN_N(a,b,c,d,e,f,n,...) ONLY_EVEN##n
#define ONLY_EVEN(...) ONLY_EVEN_N(__VA_ARGS__,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)(__VA_ARGS__)

// example:
0: ONLY_EVEN()
1: ONLY_EVEN(A)
2: ONLY_EVEN(A,B)
3: ONLY_EVEN(A,B,C)
4: ONLY_EVEN(A,B,C,D)
5: ONLY_EVEN(A,B,C,D,E)
6: ONLY_EVEN(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -E onlyeven.cpp | grep -v '#'
0:
1:
2: B
3: B
4: B,D
5: B,D
6: B,D,F
```

Note that by C/C++ spec the preprocessor is only guaranteed to accept up to 256 arguments.